# insert variable in row string python

Tags: python

i want to insert variables date and month inside string

```
filename = f'C:\Users\91956\Desktop\{date}{month}.csv.zip'
```

i get error

```
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

i think the string need to be a raw string i.e i need to write r' before string
but by doing so i am unable to insert variables in string

how to do this?

Comment: Using double quotes (i.e. "...") and forward-slash character (i.e. /) also applies here:

```
filename = f"C:/Users/91956/Desktop/{date}{month}.csv.zip"
```

Comment: @ctrl Double or single quotes make zero difference here…?!

Comment: You can use `f` and `r` together: `fr'C:\Users...'`.

Comment: used f and r together, worked

Answer (score 0):

It’s about the backslashes. You need to escape every one of them for this work.

```py
filename = f'C:\\Users\\91956\\Desktop\\{date}{month}.csv.zip'
```